# Tutorial for debian software packaging

Tags: unix

I want to learn about debian source packaging.Is there any good tutorial for that.Please give your suggestions.

Comment: not really a programming question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you're familiar with the Debian Policy Manual, found at http://www.debian.org/devel/

Once you've skimmed it to understand what's there, the New Maintainer's Guide is for you: http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/

Answer (score 0):

For a more humane introduction and step-by-step tutorial you may want to start with this [1]. It focuses on Ubuntu, but the basics stay unchanged. The official manuals are useful when you already know your way around and simply need to check some detail or option.

[1] http://blog.theroux.ca/devel/creating-ubuntu-packages-for-launchpad/